# What mobs are one block tall

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The title explains all. I'm asking for mobs that are one block tall (exactly one block). Can I use commands to change Slime's height so that it's a 1 block tall mob?

Comment: so exactly one block tall, not anything less than that

Comment: Yes. Correct. ✅✔️

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only a pig and a spider are about one block tall. All else are listed [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/archive/legacy-support/1818916-mob-height-dimentions) if you need to determine other sizes.

Comment: I reckon the guardians are exactly one block too.

Comment: nope guardians are like 0.75 blocks. tested by letting them pass over a trapdoor and a block above the actualy could pass but pigs can't